# Changing value with selenium / VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, selenium

I tried to change value with below code but error occurred.
Error message is 'sheet1 is not defined'. When i put text ex) "25-Sep-2020", it worked well.

```
Set ele = bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr//tr//tr//tr//tr//tr//tr//tr//tr[2]//td[2]//span[1]//span[1]//table[1]//tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[1]//span[1]//table[1]//tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[1]//input[1]")

attrScript = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', sheet1.range ['B2'])"

bot.ExecuteScript attrScript, ele
```

Thank you in advcane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but it seems you're mixing Javascript code (not Java!) and calling it from VBA through the SeleniumBasic library.

You can't call sheet1.range from Javascript code. It won't know what to do with it. You need to unquote that part so it can be handled by VBA instead of by Javascript.

```
attrScript = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', " & sheet1.range ['B2'] & ")"
```